# Revert to beginning of text area box after clearing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text area that I clear after a user hits enter. I want to reset the cursor to the beginning of the text area, but for some reason, it is placed at the start of the second line, and return a blank line and the text when Enter is pressed a second time. When Enter is hit a second time, the text is cleared, and the caret remains on the second line, only the first time does it go to the second line.

```
$(function(){
    var chatArea;
    chatArea = $("#chattingArea").keypress(function(event){
        if(event.which === 13){
            console.log($("#theTextbox").val());
            $("#theTextbox").val("");
            $("#theTextbox")[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

`

    
        
        
        
        ChatApp

```
<div id="chattingArea">
    <textarea id="theTextbox"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="chat">

</div>

<script src="bower_components/jQuery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="chatApp.js"></script>
</body>
```

`

Comment: Could you provide your HTML as well?

Comment: `keypress` means the character is appended *after* the key is released, either use `return false` in your event-handler or use `keyup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress` to prevent invoking the native `keypress` event in text area

**HTML**

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="chat">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. 
</textarea>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#chat").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        $("#chat").val("");
    }
})
```

[Demo JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/u9fn6/1/)

Comment: Do consider referring to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead of W3Schools.

Comment: But I do not use Mozilla firfox

Comment: Neither do I, it's not compulsory; but their documentation is superb. And accurate, without the glaring errors and hideously outdated practices/recommendations of W3Schools.

Comment: lol.. all the while I thought it was for firefox developer.. Ok, I will check it out. Thx very much.